# NDB key vs get_by_id

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Just to know if I'm mistaked or not:

**get()** operations uses NDB cache, so this (Chapter is ndb.Model class):

```
# Get the entity
chapter_key = ndb.Key('Book', long(bookId), 'Chapter', long(chapterId))
chapter = chapter_key.get()
```

can use the ndb cache if is 2nd or more read of the entity.

But if I make this?

```
Chapter.get_by_id(long(id), parent=ndb.Key('Book', long(bookId)))
```

is this managed by ndb also, or this operation is a standart db operation and don't use cache?

Comment: I think its all moving to ndb at some point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Model.get_by_id` will use the context-cache and memcache in exactly the same way as `Key.get`

Comment: So I can use both calls interchangeably, no difference except the write style. Thanks @Greg

Comment: According to the [documentation for get_by_id](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id): "This is really just a shorthand for `Key(cls, id).get()`". So yes, there seems to be no difference except the writing style.

Answer (score 1):

As Greg's answer is correct, I just wanted to mention that instead of putting keys together manually, you may use [urlsafe](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities) string, and pass it between functions.

Assuming you have a key:

```
page_key = ndb.Key('Book', long(bookId), 'Chapter', long(chapterId), 'Page', long(pageId))
```

Create urlsafe from it:

```
page_url_string = page_key.urlsafe()
```

To retrive the model, simply use:

```
page = ndb.Key(urlsafe=page_url_string).get()
```

Consider it if you're using models with several parentness, there should be no case when putting keys manually would be required, code gets messy really quick, as you need to pass additional variables between functions.